# Use drush to put a site in maintenance mode

Tags: drush, 8

`drush @mysite cget system.maintenance` shows:

> message: '@mysite is currently under maintenance. We should be back shortly. Thank you for your patience.'
>       langcode: en

Drupal 8 uses state values to record transient state, so `drush @mysite sget system.maintenance_mode` gives me a `1` or a `0`.

But, try as I may, I cannot see how to set the boolean. I've tried:

```
$ drush @mysite sset system.maintenance.mode "TRUE" --format=boolean
$ drush @mysite sget system.maintenance_mode
0
$ drush @mysite sset system.maintenance.mode "TRUE" --format=auto
$ drush @mysite sget system.maintenance_mode
0
$ drush @mysite sset system.maintenance.mode true --format=auto
$ drush @mysite sget system.maintenance_mode
0
$ drush @mysite sset system.maintenance.mode true --format=boolean
$ drush @mysite sget system.maintenance_mode 
0
```

What's the secret?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`system.maintenance_mode` is not a boolean, it is an integer:

```
drush ev "var_dump(\Drupal::state()->get('system.maintenance_mode'));"
```

Result:

```
int(0)
```

The answer to the question, how to use drush to put a site in maintenance mode:

```
drush sset system.maintenance_mode 1
```

Comment: It's worth noting here that if the site has never BEEN in maintenance mode before, the `system.maintenance_mode` variable doesn't exist, and the above `drush ev` command actually returns `bool(false)`, which is misleading.

Comment: @DaleAnderson can you update the answer to be "mo betta"?