# How can I use Drush 8 command to enable the site set up bin the Acquia DevDesktop to online mode?

Tags: drush

I forgot to put the site back online when I'd finished updating the site. How can I use Drush command to enable the site to online mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about maintenance mode. If you had use the correct term, you would have been pointed to for example the [following question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181634/) which has the info you need:

```
drush sset system.maintenance_mode 0
```